# get a certain type of elements from a array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a array of objects like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [art_id] => 76
            [title] => whatever
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [art_id] => 216
            [title] => blabla
        )

)
```

Can I somehow get a array with all `art_id`'s from it, without having to iterate it?

(like `array(76, 216)`)

Comment: csn you please clarify why you dont want to iterate it or at least explain what iterating means to you in the context of your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function getArtId($obj)
{
    return $obj->art_id;
}

$b = array_map("getArtId", $a);
print_r($b);
```

**This is indirectly an iteration**, but you do not need to write code for the loop yourself.